# How do I change my in-game name in America's Army?

Tags: americas-army-3

I logged into my account at https://americasarmy.com/account/settings, but I see no option to change my in-game name. Please see the screenshot beneath.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to change your in-game name directly through America's Army and there are ongoing requests for this feature.

However, I do believe you can change your Steam name and this will reflect in the game.